# VPN with D-Link DIR-600 Wireless Router

Tags: router, vpn, pptp

I just bought a D-Link DIR-600 Wireless Router and was hoping to setup a VPN client using the [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) firmware.

But unfortunately my hardware version of DIR-600, known as C1, is not supported by DD-WRT.

Is there another alternative?